# Stop the slider once it reaches the last image

Tags: jquery

I'm using the `cycle2` plugin. In this I want to stop the slider in thumbnail after it reaches the last image in the slider. Like, it working in previous link. In previous link, it doesn't go while at the first image is showing in the browser.

Like wise I want to stop the slider movement in last image displaying in the browser. Can anyone help?

See in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D5UzG/) for an example.